# Is there better way than write match very much?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

**HI**,
i have this code

```
let key = N001DSC29MC22HC22DD04MD09YD21
function get(key) {
  let res = {};
  res.matchNumber = key.match(/(?<=N)\d{3}/g);
  res.matchSeconds = key.match(/(?<=DSC)\d{2}/g);
  res.matchMinutes = key.match(/(?<=MC)\d{2}/g);
  res.matchHours = key.match(/(?<=HC)\d{2}/g);
  res.matchDay = key.match(/(?<=DD)\d{2}/g);
  res.matchMonth = key.match(/(?<=MD)\d{2}/g);
  res.matchYear = key.match(/(?<=YD)\d{2}/g);
  res.title = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)).title;
  res.description = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)).description;
  Object.keys(res).forEach(key => {
    if (! res[key]) delete res[key]
    if (Array.isArray(res[key])) res[key] = res[key].join('')
  })
  return res;
}
get(key)
```

As you can see my code not clean, there is any better way to do the same function. I really try and i can't do better

I Mean there is better from using `REGEXP` And `match` very mush Like this

Comment: It looks reasonable enough to me. Not perfect, but I don't see significant improvements. (A few minor improvements, though.) It could be made a bit more DRY, but at the expense of understandability IMO

Comment: *"Is there better way to write this function"* => [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you can put the initialization of the object fields inline with the creation of the object, and foreach is not the best to do side effect, try to make object `const` and use something like filter and reduce:

```js
// the snipped won't work because of the sandbox policy
let key = 'N001DSC29MC22HC22DD04MD09YD21';
function get(key) {
  const res = {
    matchNumber : key.match(/(?<=N)\d{3}/g),
    matchSeconds : key.match(/(?<=DSC)\d{2}/g),
    matchMinutes : key.match(/(?<=MC)\d{2}/g),
    matchHours : key.match(/(?<=HC)\d{2}/g),
    matchDay : key.match(/(?<=DD)\d{2}/g),
    matchMonth : key.match(/(?<=MD)\d{2}/g),
    matchYear : key.match(/(?<=YD)\d{2}/g),
    title : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)).title,
    description : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)).description,
  };
  return Object.entries(res)
    .filter(([k]) => k)
    .reduce((acc, [k,v]) => (acc[k] = v, acc), {})
}
get(key)
```

However, you can actually just avoid creating the `res` object and start with another data structure (the one that `Object.entries` will return)

```js
let key = 'N001DSC29MC22HC22DD04MD09YD21';
function get(key) {
  return [
    ['matchNumber' , key.match(/(?<=N)\d{3}/g)],
    ['matchSeconds' , key.match(/(?<=DSC)\d{2}/g)],
    ['matchMinutes' , key.match(/(?<=MC)\d{2}/g)],
    ['matchHours' , key.match(/(?<=HC)\d{2}/g)],
    ['matchDay' , key.match(/(?<=DD)\d{2}/g)],
    ['matchMonth' , key.match(/(?<=MD)\d{2}/g)],
    ['matchYear' , key.match(/(?<=YD)\d{2}/g)],
    ['title' , JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)).title],
    ['description' , JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)).description],
  ].filter(([k]) => k).reduce((acc, [k,v]) => (acc[k] = v, acc), {})
}
get(key)
```

Comment: please tell me what `(acc[k] = v, acc)` mean ?

Comment: @Max it's just like `{acc[k] = v; return acc}` but in a shorter way, if you want to fild more about it, search for _comma operator_

Comment: oh thanks very mush

Answer (score 0):

Creating an Object using `Object.fromEntries`, where entries are filtered and mapped from `Object.entries` looks a bit cleaner.

```js
console.log(get(`N001DSC29MC22HC22DD04MD09YD21`));

function get(key) {
 return Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries({
      matchNumber: key.match(/(?<=N)\d{3}/g),
      matchSeconds: key.match(/(?<=DSC)\d{2}/g),
      matchMinutes: key.match(/(?<=MC)\d{2}/g),
      matchHours: key.match(/(?<=HC)\d{2}/g),
      matchDay: key.match(/(?<=DD)\d{2}/g),
      matchMonth: key.match(/(?<=MD)\d{2}/g),
      matchYear: key.match(/(?<=YD)\d{2}/g),
      // mockup for not working localStorage in sandbox   
      title: `sometitle`,
      description: `somedescription`,
    })
    // filter only key-value pairs with a value
    .filter( ([key, value]) => value )
    // map to values with joined Arrays if applic.
    .map( ([key, value]) => 
      [key, Array.isArray(value) ? value.join('') : value ] )
  );
}
```

Alternative, labels and regexes from one [raw string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw), using one reducer to create the object.

```js
const getValuesFromKey = key => ({ 
    ...String.raw`
      ID::(?<=N)\d{3}
      Seconds::(?<=DSC)\d{2}
      Minutes::(?<=MC)\d{2}
      Hours::(?<=HC)\d{2}
      Day::(?<=DD)\d{2}
      Month::(?<=MD)\d{2}
      NoMatch::(?<=NOTHING)\d{2} // won't match anything
      Years::(?<=YD)\d{2} // will find two years `
    .split(`\n`)
    .reduce( (acc, line) => {
      line = line.replace(/\/\/.*$/, ``).trim();
      const [label, re] = line && line.split(`::`);
      const match = re && key.match(new RegExp(re, `g`));
      return match ? {...acc, [[label]]: match.join(` and `)} : acc;
    }, {}),
    Title: `someTitle`,
    Description: `someDescription` });

console.log(getValuesFromKey(`N001DSC29MC22HC22DD04MD09YD21YD45`));
//                                                         ^ extra value
```

Or use [named capture groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups). See this [stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-uza6gq?file=index.js)